# IMAP Idle Timeout

Tags: imap

Lets say I am using IMAP IDLE to monitor changes in a mail folder.

The IMAP spec says that IDLE connections should only stay alive for 30 minutes max, but it is recommended that a lower number of minutes is selected - say 20 minutes, then cancel the idle and restart.

I am wondering what would happen if the mail contents changed between the idle canceling, and the new idle being created.  An email could potentially be missed.  Given that RECENT is a bit vague, this could lead to getting a message list before the old idle ends, and a new idle starts.

But this is almost the same as polling every 20 minutes, and defeats some of the benefit of idle.

Alternatively, a new idle session could be started prior to terminating the expiring one.

But in any case, I think this problem has already been solved so here I am asking for recommendations.

Thanks,

Paul

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As you know, the purpose of IMAP IDLE command ([RFC 2177](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2177)) is to make it possible to have the server transmit *status updates* to the client in real time. In this context, *status updates* means untagged IMAP server responses such as EXISTS, RECENT, FETCH or EXPUNGE that are sent when new messages arrive, message status is updated or a message is removed.

However, these IMAP *status updates* can be returned by any IMAP command, not just the IDLE command - for example, the NOOP command (see [RFC 3501](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.1.2) section 6.1.2) can be used to poll for *server updates* as well (it predates the IDLE command). IDLE only makes it possible to get these updates more efficiently - if you don't use IDLE command, *server updates* will simply be sent by the server when the client executes another command (or even when no command is in progress in some cases) - see [RFC 3501](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-5.2) section 5.2 and 5.3 for details.

This means that if a message is changed between the IDLE canceling and the new IDLE command, the *status updates* should not be lost, just as they are not lost if you never used IDLE in the first place (and use NOOP every few seconds instead, for example) - they should simply be sent after the new IDLE command is started.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to remember last highest uid of the folder being monitored. Whenever you think there is chance that you missed update. Do a search as follows :*